# Suspend wake problem trusty

Tags: suspend

Running: Dual boot Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on an Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8, GeForce GTX 580M/PCIe/SSE2. Driver is nvidia 331.38 tested proprietary.

Upon wake from suspend I'm getting scrolling text with numbers that are increasing and a mention of mei_me along with another statement which I've forgotten.

I can't seem to find any duplicates of this problem. Appreciate your help. I like to use suspend but this has scared me off as I had to do a hard reset.

Comment: Could be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1176577 ? Anyway, seems a bug; the exact trace is important...

Comment: Please attach the screenshot / photo of these error messages.

Comment: Rmano no it's not like that.

Comment: P.H.Lin ok I'll have to do it later after my session as it forces me to reboot. The keyboard is totally unresponsive.